# Installing problem Intel graphics driver in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

**Intel graphics driver installing problem in Ubuntu 16.04.**
[image: screenshot graphic driver]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0 says that:

> This release of the Graphics Installer is targeted at Ubuntu 15.10 or
>   Fedora 23.  Ubuntu 16.04 is already current with the latest Q1 2016
>   Intel Graphics stack and therefore no Graphics Installer is needed.

Therefore, you didn't need to run the installer and even if you did, it wouldn't work, which is what you saw.